# STM32L011K4 with DMA RX using I2C data not appearing in buffer

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, i2c, dma

I am trying to query a temperature sensor (TMP007) over an I2C bus using the L011K4's DMA controller.  I've managed to get TMP007 to respond with good data, but that data isn't appearing in the buffer array that I pass my I2C DMA receive function.

What I expect to happen is that the I2C hardware is set up by the software in the Init and Read function, then the start condition is generated, the slave's address and register address are sent, then a second start/a restart is sent out followed by the slave's address again, and finally ending with a transmission of two bytes from TMP007 and a stop condition.
The data acquired from the temperature sensor *should* be appearing in a buffer that is passed into Start_Read (as MemoryBaseAddress), but that data does not appear when viewing the processor in debug mode after the read function has been called.

The Channel 3 transfer complete interrupt *is* being called, so I know the DMA has activated and managed the RX transfer, but the data doesn't appear in the desired buffer.

Here's an image of the communication being observed by a logic analyzer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fainY.png
DIO2 is connected to the onboard LED, which tells us that the DMA transfer has completed (it's the only ISR with the LED toggle).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

STM32L011K4 Datasheet: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/42/c0/ab/e5/71/7a/47/0b/DM00206508.pdf/files/DM00206508.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00206508.pdf

STM32L011K4 Reference Manual: https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00108282-ultralowpower-stm32l0x1-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

```
void I2C1_DMA_Start_Read(int SlaveAddress, int RegisterAddress, int* MemoryBaseAddress, int BufferSize) {

    I2C1->CR1 &= ~I2C_CR1_PE;                       // Disable I2C1
    DMA1_Channel3->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN;              // Disable Channel 3 DMA
    DMA1_Channel3->CCR &= ~(0x00007FFF);            // Channel 3 DMA mask

    // Configure DMA Channel 3 for 16 bit memory and peripheral, and other aliased settings (reference manual page 249, 10.4.3)
    DMA1_Channel3->CCR |=  (0b11 << 12)|(0b01 << 10)|(0b01 << 8)|DMA_CCR_MINC|DMA_CCR_TEIE|DMA_CCR_TCIE;

    DMA1_Channel3->CPAR =  (uint32_t) &(I2C1->RXDR);
    DMA1_Channel3->CMAR =  (uint32_t) MemoryBaseAddress;
    DMA1_Channel3->CNDTR = (uint16_t) BufferSize;

    DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN;               // Activate DMA channel 3

    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_NACKIE;                    // Enable no acknowledge interrupt for I2C1

    I2C1->CR2 |= ((uint8_t) (SlaveAddress << 1));   // Set up the slave address

    I2C1->CR2 &= ~I2C_CR2_RD_WRN;                   // Master requests a write transfer in order to send the register
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_PE|I2C_CR1_RXDMAEN;        // Enable I2C1 and RX DMA for I2C1
    I2C1->CR2 &= ~(0xFF << I2C_CR2_NBYTES_Pos);     // Mask byte count
    I2C1->CR2 |=  (0x01 << I2C_CR2_NBYTES_Pos);     // Transfer one byte (the slave's register address)

    while(!(I2C1->ISR & I2C_ISR_TXE));              // Wait until TX data register is empty
    I2C1->TXDR = RegisterAddress;                   // Set the transmit data to the desired register address

    I2C1->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_START;                     // Generate start condition
    while(I2C1->CR2 & I2C_CR2_START);               // Wait until hardware clears the start bit
    while(!(I2C1->ISR & I2C_ISR_TC));               // Wait until hardware clears the transmit complete bit

    I2C1->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_RD_WRN;                    // Master requests a read transfer after sending over the register address
    I2C1->CR2 &= ~(0xFF << I2C_CR2_NBYTES_Pos);     // Mask byte count
    I2C1->CR2 |=  (0x02 << I2C_CR2_NBYTES_Pos);     // Master looks for two bytes from the slave

    I2C1->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_START;                     // Generate start condition
    while(I2C1->CR2 & I2C_CR2_START);               // Wait until hardware clears the start bit

    return;
}

void DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQHandler() {
    if(DMA1->ISR & DMA_ISR_TCIF3) {
        GPIOB->ODR ^= 1 << 3;                       // Toggle the onboard LED as an indicator

        I2C1->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_STOP;                  // Generate stop condition
        while(I2C1->CR2 & I2C_CR2_STOP);            // Wait until hardware clears the stop bit
        DMA1->IFCR |= DMA_IFCR_CTCIF3;              // Clear transfer complete interrupt bit

        I2C1->CR1 &= ~I2C_CR1_PE;                   // Disable I2C1
        DMA1_Channel3->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN;          // Disable Channel 3 DMA

    } else if(DMA1->ISR & DMA_ISR_TEIF3) {

        I2C1->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_STOP;                  // Generate stop condition (if I2C comm is already stopped on error, delete this and following line)
        while(I2C1->CR2 & I2C_CR2_STOP);            // Wait until hardware clears the stop bit

        DMA1->IFCR |= DMA_IFCR_CTEIF3;              // Clear transfer error interrupt bit

        I2C1->CR1 &= ~I2C_CR1_PE;                   // Disable I2C1
        DMA1_Channel3->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN;          // Disable Channel 3 DMA

    }

    return;
}

void I2C1_IRQHandler() {
    if(I2C1->ISR & I2C_ISR_NACKF) {
        //GPIOB->ODR ^= 1 << 3;                     // Toggle the onboard LED as an indicator
        I2C1->ICR |= I2C_ICR_NACKCF;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: `if(magic_numbers == USED) then expext_no_help();`

Comment: Apologies for not including the datasheets.  I have removed the magic numbers that could be replaced by a stm32 macro.  Some of the values were taken straight from the l011k4 reference manual, so I haven't touched those.